# Using bilateral filter with PCL

Tags: point-cloud-library

I'm trying to use the bilateral filter (not fast bilateral filter) with PCL 1.7, as I have an unordered point cloud. I have been able to make other PCL code snippets work (so it's not the conversion code), and I can't find documentation on how to make this particular filter work. I'm trying the following code, but I get a memory access violation when calling applyFilter:

```
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> ());
    // convert from custom format to pcl format
    convert(world_pts, left_intensities, cloud);

    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZI>);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> cloud_filtered;

    pcl::BilateralFilter<pcl::PointXYZI> fbFilter; 
    fbFilter.setInputCloud(cloud); 
    fbFilter.setHalfSize(1.0);
    fbFilter.setStdDev(0.2);
    fbFilter.applyFilter(cloud_filtered);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function:

```
void pcl::BilateralFilter< PointT >::applyFilter ( PointCloud & output)
```

expects a reference to the output point cloud
and thats why you get a memory access violation

use:

```
fbFilter.applyFilter(*cloud_filtered);
```

instead ;)

Comment: Actually you should use filter() instead of applyFilter(). There is some additional setup that needs to happen. Am wondering if applyFilter should be a protected function so it is not so confusing?